# How to create Next() method in an Object class

Tags: java, class, object, arraylist, iterator

I have a class called `Tile` that has the follow methods:

```
public Tile(Shape tile, Color color, int position), getTile(),
```

`setTile(), getColor(), setColor(), getPosition(), setPosition()`

Now using `for(Tile item: tiles)` I want to  have a `item.Next()` that will move to the next index.

Btw `tiles` is `List<Tile> tiles = new ArrayList<Tile>` contains all the tiles, color and position.

So my question is how do I implement `Next()` in the `Tile` class? I can't do `item++` since its of type `Tile`, etc.

Thanks for the help.

Note my `Tile` class and `ArrayList tiles` is located in different files

Comment: How can `tiles` include all the tiles if it is `List<String> tiles = new ArrayList<String>()`. Shouldn't it be `List<Tile> tiles = new ArrayList<Tile>();`? If you change tiles to be that you can simple do for(Tile tile: files) { tile.setColor(color); } or whatever you have to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For loop also does the required as the below code,

```
List<Tile> tiles = new ArrayList<Tile>();
Iterator<Tile> tileIterator= tiles.iterator();
while (tileIterator.hasNext()) {
     Tile tile = tileIterator.next();
     tile.setColor("green");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply put it in to an iterator.

```
    Iterator<Tile> tileIterator= tiles.iterator();
    while (tileIterator.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(tileIterator.next());
    }
```

**Edit**

Change your

```
    List<String> tiles = new ArrayList<String>
```

to

```
    List<Tile> tiles = new ArrayList<Tile>();
```

Then add the "tiles" items to this list. Then use below code

```
   Iterator<Tile> tileIterator = tiles.iterator();

    Tile t;
    while (tileIterator.hasNext()) {
        t = tileIterator.next();
        System.out.println(t.getColor().toString());
        t.setColor(your_color);
        System.out.println(t.getColor().toString());
    }
```

**Note**

Once you get the tile object to t you can use any method in the class Tile by using the t object.

Comment: What If I want to access at the same setColor() method from tile, how do I use it with the iterator? tileIterator.setColor() wouldnt work

Comment: @evgeni-mironov: Try the edit section and see. You should add you tiles objects to the List using tiles.add(your_tile_object)

Comment: the Tiles was actually already a type <Tile>, my bad about that, your way works. Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement Iterable, [source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html), then you'll be able to use your class in a "for-each-loop".

Comment: I thought about iterator, but I how do i access setColor() with iterator , because I need to set a tile to a color